# How can I set up precision in a double column in Derby database?

Tags: java, sql, derby

I am using these codes to create a table in derby database.

```
    CREATE TABLE "USED_BANKACCOUNT"
    (
       "FYEAR" VARCHAR(10),
        "NUM" DOUBLE,
       "USERNAME" VARCHAR(20)
        );
```

My data is stored like this.

```
   FYEAR              NUM                  USERNAME
   ---------------------------------------------------
   2013               10.5                 Pranjal
   2013               5.25                 Pranjal
   2013               9.0                  Bimal 
   ---------------------------------------------------
```

But I want my data to be stored like this

```
   FYEAR              NUM                  USERNAME
   ---------------------------------------------------
   2013               10.50                 Pranjal
   2013               5.25                  Pranjal
   2013               9.00                  Bimal 
   ---------------------------------------------------
```

What should I do with my `DOUBLE` datatype ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a DECIMAL [type](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj15260.html) with a defined precision and scale:

```
CREATE TABLE "USED_BANKACCOUNT" (
    "FYEAR" VARCHAR(10),
    "NUM" DECIMAL(5, 2),
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR(20)
);
```

The `precision` represents the total number of digits allowed in the number(both to the left and the right of the decimal poin), and the `scale` represents the number of fractional digits allowed. So the above example defines a decimal number that will allow a maximum of 5 digits, with 2 digits in the fractional component.