# Java Apache Derby - DECIMAL Column data is 0.001 out put is 0.0

Tags: java, derby

I'm trying to display a fractional decimal in the output of my java code. I'm creating the column in the sql statement as DECIMAL, in the output I cast it as a double. When the data in the column is for example 3.01 it displays correctly, however, if the data in the column is 0.001 it only displays 0.0. I'm using apache derby and java. The column in question is "BatAvg". Code below:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class CreateDBDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Create database
    String databaseURL = "jdbc:derby:booksdb;create=true";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL))
    {
        // create a SQL instruction that the connection object will execute
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        // if the book table does not exist, execute the code in the if block
        if (!doesTableExists("Players", conn))
        {
            // create a table named book
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE Players (PlayerNumber int, FName varchar(20), LName varchar(20), Psn varchar(2), BatAvg DECIMAL)";
            statement.execute(sql);
            // insert two rows of data into the book table
            sql = "INSERT INTO Players VALUES (27, 'Carlton', 'Fisk', 'C', 0.001),(3, 'Jimmie', 'Foxx', '1B', 0.002)";
            statement.execute(sql);
        }

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Players";
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (result.next())
        { screen
            //System.out.println(result.getString("PlayerNumber"));
            int playerNumber = result.getInt("PlayerNumber");
            String fName = result.getString("Fname");
            String lName = result.getString("Lname");
            String posit = result.getString("Psn");
            double batting = result.getDouble("BatAvg");
            System.out.println(playerNumber+", "+fName+" "+lName+", "+posit+", "+batting);
        }
        // shut down all databases and the derby engine.
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");

    }// end of try block
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        // A clean shutdown always throws SQL exception XJ015, which can be ignored.
        if (ex.getSQLState().equals("XJ015"))
        {
            System.out.println("Derby shutdown normally");
        }
        else
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }// end of catch block
} // end of main method
private static boolean doesTableExists(String tableName, Connection conn)

throws SQLException
{
    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
    ResultSet result = meta.getTables(null, null, tableName.toUpperCase(), null);
    return result.next();
}
} // end of class
```

Comment: I believe you have to set the number of decimal places. See [DECIMAL documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj132.html#HDRSII-SQLJ-15260) and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/16014730/636009